# Why is npm start (after create-react-app) failing to run?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

After I create a sample react app using create-react-app, npm start fails.

I have tried this using node 11.4 and 10.4 (npm 6.4.1)

```
npm install create-react-app -g
create-react-app t2
cd t2
npm start
```

### Expected

To be able to start simple react server to hit in browser at localhost:3000

## Actual

Server did not start, got this in my terminal:

> ```
> $ npm start
>
> > t2@0.1.0 start /Users/samr/dev/githubs/react/t2
> > react-scripts start
>
> /Users/samr/dev/githubs/react/t2/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65
>       throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
>       ^
>
> Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean
>     at Ajv.addKeyword (/Users/samr/dev/githubs/react/t2/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65:13)
>     at module.exports (/Users/samr/dev/githubs/react/t2/node_modules/ajv-errors/index.js:10:7)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/samr/dev/githubs/react/t2/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:22:1)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! t2@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the t2@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/samr/.npm/_logs/2019-02-09T23_19_40_848Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768

Comment: I'm running into this as well. Npm start worked fine for me for an app I created last night, but today I tried to use create-react-app for a new project, and in the new project npm start is not working for me. Copying over my node_modules folder from my previous app did help as a temporary workaround, but once I tried installing react router into my new app and then running npm start, I'm running into this error once again.

Comment: same here, maybe you can check this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768, changing the file in file **node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js** as someone says here solved it for now as a quick fix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick fix is mentioned here :

- [GITHUB - webpack/issues/8768](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768)

Essentially go to **`node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js`** and comment out lines 64 and 65.

Comment: There is no ajv folder in my node_modules directory

Answer (score 11):

As @atsnam has said, you can find the resolution here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768.

#### If you use yarn

add below to package.json

```
"resolutions": {
  "ajv": "6.8.1"
}
```

then run `yarn install`

**if you use npm**

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

That worked for me

Comment: it won't work if you deploy the app. i suggest adding `"ajv": "6.8.1"` into the dependencies instead

Comment: Just modify to npm install --save ajv@6.8.1

Comment: if you're using npm 5 or newer, all installs should be saved to `package.json` by default

Comment: I had the same issue with a TomTom ReactJS sample I got off GitHub. This answer resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

just add `resolutions` to your package.json like this:

```
  { 
    "dependencies": {
      ...
    }
    "resolutions": {
      "ajv": "6.8.1"
    }
  }
```

then run `npm install`. if you use yarn, `yarn install`

Comment: I added this, did the npm install, but npm start still fails the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion in Github answers the below change has enabled me to work.

```
To fix this error, just change:
Line 14: `errors: 'full',`
to:
Line 14: `errors: true`
in file **node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js**
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Instead i did this:

- deleted node_modules folder.
- cd to project parent directory.

  npm install
  npm start

This worked like a charm.